# Click counter wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

Всем привет!
Есть сайт, на нем располагаются файлы для скачивания, необходимо к ссылкам прикрутить счетчик кликов с последующим выводом статистики на отдельную страницу по типу "Название файла - n скачиваний".

Название файлов и ссылка для скачивания генерируется через стандартный, немного измененный `wp-playlist` (`/wp-includes/media.php`) следующим образом:

Название -

```
<span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title"><?php
                /* translators: playlist item title */
                printf( _x( '&#8220;%s&#8221;', 'playlist item title' ), '{{ data.title }}' );
            ?></span>
```

Ссылка -

```
<a title="Скачать песню" href="{{ data.src }}" download="">Скачать песню</a>
```

Статистика нужна только админу, думаю можно результат записывать в txt и выводить на экран по ссылке.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос, больше выглядит как сделайте за меня :)

Comment: Да я любому ответу буду рад, варианту реализации, ссылке на мануал по подобным темам:)